# How do I use gnuplot to create a 3d phase-space plot?

Tags: encryption, gnuplot

Have a look at this webpage - [enclosed but not encrypted](http://www.h-online.com/security/features/Enclosed-but-not-encrypted-746199.html)

> For a three-dimensional phase-space plot, the sequence a, b, c, d, e,
>   f, etc. can be used as space coordinates (a-b, b-c, c-d), (b-c, c-d,
>   d-e), (c-d, d-e, e-f), etc. Patterns in the plot created reveal
>   recurring relations between subsequent sequences. In this phase plot,
>   50,000 16-bit random numbers would produce an unstructured cloud of
>   dots.

I want to do exactly the same kind of thing. I have a binary file (about 10 MB) and I'd like to create some nice gnuplot style graphs like they have on that web page.

What do I type into gnuplot to make that happen?

Comment: What is the data in that file you want to display? The individual bytes?

Comment: @JanDoggen - yes please.  I want to recreate the plots as shown in the given website, but using my own data.  I want to use their gnuplots as a test of some data that I have.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a dump of your binary file in a format suitable for gnuplot. For convenience I used `hexdump` with a custom output format, which we need to store in a file, e.g. as `gnuplot.hdp` (in principle the format string can get passed via a command line option, but then we will run into too much nested quotes in the gnuplot script):

   ```
   $ cat gnuplot.hdp
   3/1 "%03d " "\n"

   $ hexdump -f gnuplot.hdp random.data | head -n 4
   236 027 076
   070 243 055
   047 115 211
   184 206 073
   ```
2. Plot the data with gnuplot. In the simplest case, we plot bytes `1, 2, 3` and `4, 5, 6` etc. as `x, y, z` coordinates:

   ```
   set parametric
   unset border
   unset xtics
   unset ytics
   unset ztics
   splot "< hexdump -f gnuplot.hdp random.data" using ($1):($2):($3) notitle
   ```

   A file with random numbers shows -- not surprisingly -- a rather random scatter plot:

   [image]

   But if we use e.g. a badly compressed file, like a simple bitmap, we see a structure (here it's a line):

   [image]
3. If we want to resemble the plot in the cited article a little better, we need `6/1 "%03d " "\n"` as `hexdump` format, so that we get six bytes per line. And we have to extend the `splot` command in gnuplot:

   ```
   splot "< hexdump -f gnuplot.hdp random.data" u ($1-$2):($2-$3):($3-$4) ls 1 not, '' u ($2-$3):($3-$4):($4-$5) ls 1 not, '' u ($3-$4):($4-$5):($5-$6) ls 1 not
   ```

   `gnuplot` treats `u` as an abbreviation for `using` and `not` for `notitle` to keep things short.

   For the bitmap we get now a nice looking object;

   [image]

   the random data looks like that:

   [image]
4. Be aware, that we analyze the data in blocks of 6 bytes, i.e. if only the 6th and 7th byte (or multiples of these) are correlated, the plots won't reveal that.
5. `gnuplot` should handle a 10MB input file easily, but especially the rotation can get slow -- depending on your computing power.

Comment: [This answer to the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892901/how-do-i-create-a-3d-phase-space-plot-in-gnuplot) may be of interest to you.